# How to bind a View/ViewModel to Properties.Settings.Default using Caliburn Micro?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

Can I bind a View directly to settings in my Properties.Settings.Default? Or I need to create properties with the same name and refresh the values manually?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=BrandOfBeerOfChoice}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the small app I created a Settings entry called `BrandOfBeerOfChoice`.